# Python PyQt4 QSlider Interval bigger than 1

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, qslider

I am making a gui with multiple QSlider in a scrollarea, for some of my sliders i need an interval of 10 and not 1.

When i open the gui the ticks are correct and have a jump of 10, but when i return the current value i can still get values that are between the ticks, for example:

```
slider = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
slider.setMaximum(90)
slider.setMinimum(10)
slider.setTickInterval(10)
slider.setTickPosition(QtGui.QSlider.TicksBelow)
slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_value_change)
```

The function is just:

```
def slider_value_change(self,value):
    print(value)
```

This code will return 10,11,12,13... instead of 10,20...

Is there a way to keep the value so it will only return the tick values?
Also is there a way to add a lable to the tick with its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to solve this is to think in terms of the **number** of slider positions, rather than their specific **values**.

For a value range of 10-90 with an interval of 10, there are only 9 possible positions. So the slider should be configured like this:

```
slider = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
slider.setMinimum(1)
slider.setMaximum(9)
slider.setTickInterval(1)
slider.setSingleStep(1) # arrow-key step-size
slider.setPageStep(1) # mouse-wheel/page-key step-size
slider.setTickPosition(QtGui.QSlider.TicksBelow)
slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider_value_change)
```

Now all you need to do is multiply by 10 to get the required value:

```
def slider_value_change(self, value):
    print(value * 10)
```

The basic idea here, is that setting an interval of 1 eliminates the possibility of intervening values - so it is only possible to drag the slider through a fixed set of positions.

---

On the question of tick-mark labels, see:

- [Qt slider widget with tick text labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27661877/984421)
- [Qwt (Qt Widgets for Technical Applications)](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/controlscreenshots.html)
- [PyQwt (PyQt bindings for Qwt)](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/gui-examples.html)

---

PS: If you want mouse-clicks to jump straight to a slider position, see:

- [QSlider mouse direct jump](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11132597/984421)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no, there is no trivial solution to this so your best bet is to sanitize the value in `self.slider_value_change`.

Comment: Is it also true for the labels? do i need to add them manualy by position or is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can update the slider value to the correct one whenever it changes. Just make sure you don't run into a feedback loop.

Comment: i meant the labels for each tick(10,20,30...), is there a way to add them when creating the slider?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661877/qt-slider-widget-with-tick-text-labels